# Plase help me with writting this method

Tags: java, string

/*I have write a method. User will a input like m/h/d. Then he will enter again different e.g. method. The output must be "Yes m/h/d occurs in method" */

```
 public static boolean occursIn(String pattern, String str){

for(int i=0; i<= text.length()-1; i+=2){
char a = pattern.charAt(i);
  if (text.contain(a)){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Ok. What is the question ?

Comment: m h d these characters must be in order

Comment: I wrote  comment in codes

Comment: `"I wrote comment in codes"` -- Please don't. If you have a specific question, please write it out, separate from your code. You're asking volunteers to put in effort to help you and so you should make it as easy as possible to understand your problem. So please put more effort into this -- what's wrong with your current code? What errors are you seeing? What don't you understand?

Comment: so Sorry I'm new here. I'll make efforts then if ı can not make it, I'll ask it again.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is `str` variable but in method the variable is `text`, please check it.